# Can deque store char* in C?

Tags: c, file, types, deque

I need a deque of strings read from a txt file. They are read successfully (I checked it by printing them out in while.

```
    while ((read = getdelim(&word, &len, ' ', fp)) != -1) 
{
    printf("!%s\n", word); 
    strcpy(s, word);
    printf(" read string is : %s\n", s);
    deque_push_back(d,s);
}
```

The code works. The only thing is that when I'm trying to print the deque, all the values are "aaa", but here's the actual contents of my file:
hhh aaa hfhf hhh nnn bbbb aaa bbb aaa

I tryed out to push values this way:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    char * s = "ssss";
    deque_push_back(d,s);
}
s = "llll";
deque_push_back(d,s);
```

This code works totally fine and all the values in my deque are correct.

I have no idea what's the problem and will be really thankfull if someone can help me.

Comment: You are storing always the same pointer in your deque; you're just changing what's in the memory to which it points.  You need to not just `strcpy()`, but create a new object to copy the data into.  If you have `strdup()` then that should help.  Otherwise, for each string, `malloc()`sufficient memory to `strcpy()` into, and enqueue the pointer to that space.

Comment: *The code works. The only thing is that...*. The conventional description of this situation would be *The code doesn't work*.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing always the same pointer in your deque; you're just changing what's in the memory to which it points.  You need to not just `strcpy()`, but create a new object to copy the data into.  If you have `strdup()` then that should help.  Otherwise, for each string, `malloc()`sufficient memory to `strcpy()` into, and enqueue the pointer to that space.
                    – John Bollinger